# What is the logic used to break down multiple lambda variables in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to reason through why the result of the following would be 8 but I'm a little stuck.

```
f = lambda x,y: lambda z: (x)(y)(z)
print((f)(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z*2)(3)(4))
```

I know that the next step would be to substitute f into the line as shown below, but this is where I get lost.

```
ans = (lambda x,y: lambda z: (x)(y)(z))(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z*2)(3)(4)
```

From my understanding, f requires three arguments in total, one in this (x,y) format and another one like (z).

```
(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z*2)(3)(4)
```

I think 3 should be the argument for lambda x and nothing should be inputted for lambda y. I think 4 would then be the argument for lambda z.

This leads me to think (3,8) is what is returned for (lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z*2), but then I don't have an input for lambda z in the original f.

I could use explanation of how this is processed to give a final answer of 8. Apologies for any formatting errors.

Comment: Is this for your own edification? This is awful code you shouldn't *have* to reason about because it never should have been written. Try writing the equivalent in normal function definitions -- it'll be a lot easier to reason about. Also, try a debugger that lets you trace the code path in steps.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently a student and this was one of the problems I was stuck on. I'll give your suggestions a try! Thanks!

Comment: `f()` only takes two parameters - `x` and `y`.  It returns a function that takes the `z` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's give a name to some of those lambdas:

```
const = lambda x: (lambda y: x)
double = lambda z: (z*2)
```

And [eta-reduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction) the `lambda z:...` inside `f` (that is `lambda z: ( x(y) )(z) -> x(y)`):

```
f = lambda x, y: x(y)
```

We can now rewrite that expression as `( ( f(const, double) )(3) )(4)`.

Reducing, we get:

```
f(const, double) -> const(double) -> lambda y: double
(lambda y: double)(3) -> double
double(4) -> 8
```